# Do Anglo-Catholics encourage closed Communion?

Tags: communion, anglicanism, canon-law

Closed Communion seems to be commonly required in churches with more physical views of the Real Presence (excluding, of course, Reformed churches that hold to Calvin's "spiritual presence" view). The Orthodox, Roman Catholics, and many Lutherans all practice closed Communion. Most Anglican churches, however, practice open Communion. Are there any Anglo-Catholic churches that have tried to restrict their Communion practice to church members, as do most churches with similar theology?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: Not in my experience. Nor does the Catholic Church either...

Comment: @curiousdannii "Closed communion" typically means closed to those outside the denomination, not outside the congregation. By that definition, the Catholic Church absolutely _does_ practice closed communion.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Is it different at weddings? Because the mass was offered to all then.

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude The RCC does have exceptions to an absolutely closed communion. See, http://www.ewtn.com/expert/answers/intercommunion.htm
As

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, but it's misleading to say that, given that one of the necessary conditions to receive Catholic communion as a non-Catholic is "manifests Catholic faith in the sacraments," i.e. has Catholic belief.

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude Right, but the same can be said of why Catholics do not "re-baptize" persons who come into the Church. As long as you believe, as Catholics do, that you must be baptized in the name of the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, you do not need to be "re-baptized." Therefore, that would be the "manifest[ation of] Catholic faith in the sacraments." Furthermore, isn't that true of most denominations: if you follow our rules, you can play our game.

Comment: @Andrew No, denominations that practice "open communion" do not require one to believe the same things as that denomination.

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude That is my point exactly.

Comment: The RCC does not, strictly speaking, have a closed-communion policy in that members of Orthodox churches are permitted to receive, though most don't. However, I know of no Anglican church that would have even a similar policy.

Answer (score 2):

Some more conservative Anglo-Catholics may prefer a policy of closed communion, but in the Episcopal Church there is a policy of communion being offered to all who are baptized.

Comment: Good find, but better if you can [edit] to show a reference.